# PHP Arrays to JSON data

Tags: php, json

I have arrays that looks like this:

```
Array ( [multi_YTnsPrfuB832.jpg] => gray [multi_hUORaTux1bI.jpg] => episode [multi_Ijtxz4U0iaq_.jpg] => fidgetq [multi_m0QWCyfVjDKh.jpg] => fidget2 )
```

the data inside the bracket is a URL and the value is the name. I want to encode this to be a json data to be something like this:

```
{ "offers":
    {
        "url":multi_YTnsPrfuB832.jpg,
        "name":"gray"
    },
    {
        "url":multi_hUORaTux1bI.jpg,
        "name":"episode"
    },
    {
        "url":multi_Ijtxz4U0iaq_.jpg,
        "name":"fidgetq"
    },
    {
        "url":multi_m0QWCyfVjDKh.jpg,
        "name":"fidget2"
    }

}
```

I'm fairly new to json so if someone has an idea how to implement this using php. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reformat your array all you need to do is iterate it and push to a new array in the format you are looking for. The [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function will turn an array into a JSON formatted string.

```
$array = /*your array*/;
$offers = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $offers[] = ['url' => $key, 'name' => $value,];
}
$json = json_encode(['offers' => $offers,]);
echo $json;
```

Comment: wow! this is the solution im looking. youre a life saver sir! thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can using json_encode($myArray)

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function like this

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

and more [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)